# Trying to run an app on Window Task Scheduler, the task will just run till it time out

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-task-scheduler

I want to run my app with Window's Task Scheduler.
The issue I am facing right now is that the app runs fine when I manually run it(.exe). When I set up the schedule task to run it, it started the app(I can see it being run in task manager), but it is running forever(runs till it time out). The amount of time it take to run from start to finish is around few seconds when I ran it manually.

My guess is that the Task Scheduler is stuck at the Form window? but I do have logic in the Form load method that will auto close the form when it is done.

Follow up: I added the log in the form load method, and the log file didn't get created, is that mean my form didn't load?

Comment: if your business logic does not need any user interaction , use console application

Comment: You should show the code that initializes the application (Program.cs, the starting Form's Constructor and the `OnLoad()` method / `Load` event handler, if you have any code there. I.e., all that's happening when the application starts. -- Are you showing your main Form iconized in the Tray Notification Area? Or the starting Form is supposed to show up when it's done initializing?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, but I'll suggest you put logs at the start of the application, in the end, and at some parts where you feel it could be breaking. In this way, you will have an idea

Here is the example [repository](https://github.com/GSKKC/Scheduler)

Comment: I added the log in the form load method, and the log file didn't get created, is that mean my form didn't load? It rans fine when i manually ran the app, like the log file get created as expected to, but when I run the Task Scheduler i see the app got started, but non of the log got hit

Comment: `if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
                        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
                        ).Count() > 1)
            {
                log.Info("Previous Task is already running...");

            }`

Yes, your application is not getting hit, make sure the user has all the right permissions to access,run the application. Additionally you can use above code to verify whether app is hit or not